# Keras custom loss function: variable with shape of batch_size (y_true)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, loss-function

When implementing a custom loss function in Keras, I require a `tf.Variable` with the shape of the batch size of my input data `(y_true, y_pred)`.

```
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):

    counter = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(K.shape(y_true)[0], dtype=tf.float32))
    ...
```

However, this produces the error:

```
You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'dense_17_target' with dtype float and shape [?,?]
```

If I fix the batch_size to a value:

```
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):

    counter = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(batch_size, dtype=tf.float32))
    ...
```

such that `|training_set| % batch_size` and `|val_set| % batch_size` are equal to zero, everything works fine.

Are there any suggestions, why the assignment of the variable with batch size based on the shape of the input (`y_true` and `y_pred`) does not work?

**SOLUTION**

I found a satisfying solution that works.
I initialized the variable with the max batch_size possible (specified during model build time) and used the `K.shape(y_true)[0]` only for slicing the variable. That way it works perfectly. Here the code:

```
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    counter = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(batch_size, dtype=tf.float32))
    ...
    true_counter = counter[:K.shape(y_true)[0]]
    ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not work because `K.shape` returns you a symbolic shape, which is a tensor itself, not a tuple of int values. To get the value from a tensor, you have to evaluate it under a session. See [documentation](https://keras.io/backend/#shape) for this. To get a real value prior to evaluation time, use `K.int_shape`: https://keras.io/backend/#int_shape

However, `K.int_shape` also not gonna work here, as it is just some static metadata and won't normally reflect the current batch size, but has a placeholder value `None`.

The solution you found (have a control over the batch size and use it inside the loss) is indeed a good one.

I believe the problem is because you need to know the batch size at the definition time to build the Variable, but it will be known only during the session run time.

If you were working with it as with a tensor, it should be ok, see this [example](https://github.com/pierluigiferrari/ssd_keras/blob/master/keras_loss_function/keras_ssd_loss.py#L128).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the input! Especially the different approach of dealing with the batch_size as with a tensor made me figure out the solution.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution is to create a Variable and change its shape dynamically using `tf.assign` with `validate_shape=False`:

```
counter = tf.Variable(0.0)
...
val = tf.zeros(tf.shape(y_true)[:1], 0.0)
counter = tf.assign(counter, val, validate_shape=False)
```