# how to get the real shape of batch_size which is none in keras

Tags: keras, reshape, keras-layer, autoencoder, tf.keras

When implementing a custom layer in Keras, I need to know the real size of batch_size. my shape is `(?,20)`.

**questions:**

**1.** What is the best way to change `(?,20)` to `(batch_size,20)`.

I have looked into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54388842/keras-custom-loss-function-variable-with-shape-of-batch-size-y-true) but it can not adjust to my problem.

I can pass the `batch_size` to this layer. In that case, I need to reshape `(?,20)` to `(batch_size,20)`, how can I do that?

**2.** Is it the best way to that, or is there any builtin function that can get the real `batch_size` while building and running the model?

This is my layer:

```
from scipy.stats import entropy
from keras.engine import Layer
import keras.backend as K
import numpy as np

class measure(Layer):

    def __init__(self, beta, **kwargs):
        self.beta = beta
        self.uses_learning_phase = True
        self.supports_masking = True
        super(measure, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def call(self, x):
        return K.in_train_phase(self.rev_entropy(x, self.beta), x)

    def get_config(self):
        config = {'beta': self.beta}
        base_config = super(measure, self).get_config()
        return dict(list(base_config.items()) + list(config.items()))

    def rev_entropy(self, x, beta):

        entropy_p_t_w = np.apply_along_axis(entropy, 1, x)

        con = (beta / (1 + entropy_p_t_w)) ** 1.5

        new_f_w_t = x * (con.reshape(con.shape[0], 1))

        norm_const = 1e-30 + np.sum(new_f_w_t, axis=0)
        for t in range(norm_const.shape[0]):
            new_f_w_t[:, t] /= norm_const[t]

        return new_f_w_t
```

And here is where I call this layer:

```
encoded = measure(beta=0.08)(encoded)
```

I am also using fit_generator if it can help at all:

```
autoencoder.fit_generator(train_gen, steps_per_epoch=num_train_steps, epochs=NUM_EPOCHS,
                                    validation_data=test_gen, validation_steps=num_test_steps, callbacks=[checkpoint])
```

The dimension of the `x` passed to the layer is (?,20) and that's why I can not do my calculation.

Thanks:)

Comment: Not super sure, but it sounds like the same as in Keras's RNN layers in `stateful` mode, which does require an explicit batch size to be passed to the layer. Might check out the source code for that.

Comment: @TheLoneDeranger Thanks for answering, can you point out a link which I can follow. I went to some links but I could not get it to fit my problem!